# Passing callback functions to child components, is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I get the error `_videos.filteredVideo) is not a function` when I try and dispatch an action from a child component. How can I pass an `action` to my child component?

I have this container component:

```
class SearchScreen extends React.Component {

  filterVideo = payload => {
    filteredVideo(payload);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Search {...this.props} filterVideo={this.filterVideo} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  filteredVideo: () => dispatch(filteredVideo())
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    videos: state.videos
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchScreen);
```

Child component:

```
  filteredVideo = filteredData => {
        const { filterVideo } = this.props;

        filterVideo(filteredData); //_videos.filteredVideo) is not a function
    };

    filterList = event => {
        let videos = this.state.initialVideos;

        let {
            nativeEvent: { text }
        } = event;
        let filteredData = videos.filter(item =>
            item.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
        );

        this.filteredVideo(filteredData);
    };
```

Comment: The `filteredVideo()` method you  are dispatching in `mapDispatchToProps` where is that defined ?

Comment: Its defined in my container:   `filterVideo = payload => {
    filteredVideo(payload);
  };`

Comment: It seems to be have been defined inside the `SearchScreen` class , if so can you move it outside ?

Comment: Can I just pass the function down with `...this.props`? As its in `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: from the edited question I understand that you want to pass the method to child component, and you have done it  as ` <Search {...this.props} filterVideo={this.filterVideo} />` , this should work .But  if you are planning to handle `filterVideo` in a seperate `actions.js` file , then i reckon your `mapDispatchToProps` will help